# Is there any command to Windows like 'who' to Linux

Tags: windows

I want to retrieve a list of all the users who have logged in locally or remotely on Windows , Is there any command to Windows like 'who' to Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On windows machines, it would be smart, to get acquaint with the powersehll:
http://learn-powershell.net/2010/11/01/quick-hit-find-currently-logged-on-users/
Most administrative task could easily be done with powersehll.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730963.aspx

Comment: There's this nice collection of scripts for Powershell to get the logged in users: http://www.peetersonline.nl/2008/11/oneliner-get-logged-on-users-with-powershell/

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use who. In fact who is not a Linux command. Rather it is one of the GNU tools, and these are available on Windows too. There are a variety of Windows ports of GNU. There's cygwin of course, but I personally use GnuWin32.

You can do it natively using WMI

```
wmic ComputerSystem Get UserName
```

And there are plenty of other third party tools. For example the very useful SysInternals tools offers PsLoggedOn.

Answer (score 0):

Command name is "whoami", and "whoami" command does not work in Windows XP without the SP2 Support Tools download. The command is not native to the OS. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18546

use command like c:>whoami